# How to update pip in streamlit hosting platform

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, hosting, streamlit

I have created a very small web application which uses machine learning model in its backend, I tried to host the application through streamlit hosting platform,

But initially i got a error saying modules not found so I put in the list of modules in requirements.txt

But when streamlit tries to install the modules and encounters tensorflow, it throws an error asking to update pip since it uses an older version of pip

I have verified twice that I run the latest version of pip in my local computer now how can I make streamlit use the latest version of pip to install tensorflow successfully

I am new to python and machine learning so please explain in an easy to understand way

Any response is at most welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to your code and redeployment it to Streamlit Hosting:

```
!pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: I will surely give it a try and inform you, thank your for your response

Comment: I don't know why you have included the "!" symbol before pip but I did try upgrading the pip using the same command but never worked.